# Use PHP to Save Webpage Content on the same URL

Tags: php

I need to use PHP to save a webpage which has content generated in an iFrame, Its like this..

I have a .PHP file with an iFrame (inside which it opens a URL which produces dynamic content) inside it.

I want the Php file to save the generated content (or the whole source) to the server.

I tried the @file_get_contents but how do I specify the URL of the same .php file since it is in iFrame..?

Also how can I output the entire HTTP header into a file with PHP?

I know its a bit unclear but bear with me please!

I tried this code but it doesn't work.

CODE

```
<html>
<body>
<?php

function curPageURL() {
 $pageURL = 'http';
 if ($_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on") {$pageURL .= "s";}
 $pageURL .= "://";
 if ($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] != "80") {
  $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].":".$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
 } else {
  $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
 }
 return $pageURL;
}
$contents = @file_get_contents($pageURL);
$fp = fopen("file.txt", "a");
fputs($fp, "
$contents
");
fclose($fp);
?>
<iframe src="LINK TO WEBPAGE HERE" />
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks

Comment: How is the code for iframe being generated ? Paste some code snippet for more clarification of your question.

Comment: I have added a sample code. :)

Comment: How are going to generate "LINK TO WEBPAGE HERE" ? I mean to say if you are writing the above code you will have that link and use CURL. What exactly being rendered in that iframe ?

Comment: Its link to a webpage (simple HREF link) which produces dynamic content on every refresh.. I only need to grab that content generated.. I am sure when you save the source of the .PHP file in the server the source of the generated content inside iFrame is also saved..

Comment: Can you explain how are you generating `HREF` ? or is your `curPageURL()` generating that URL ? can you paste the code that is generating that URL or getting it from database ?

Comment: Sorry but I can't post the URL here.. It is from another server which is generating the content and getting displayed in the iframe, I want to save the source of the generated content. Thanks for taking your time in replying :)

Comment: That means you are getting that URL in your PHP script right ? Then use that URL with CURL http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php If you are generating that iframe, then you should poses that URL.

Comment: Yep that is right, I think I got an idea of where to proceed! Thanks a ton man :) Will reply here if I get stuck again!

Answer (score 3):

First of all never use `file_get_contents()` wih URLS because it is disabled on most (well configured) servers. You can use a fantastic library `cURL`

http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php

```
<?php

$ch = curl_init("http://HREF of iframe here");
$fp = fopen("some filename name here", "w");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
fclose($fp);
?>
```

which will store complete page into provided file.

Comment: Wow! Thanks man.. One more thing.. can we also save the URL in the iFrame to the file.. I mean once the iFrame generates the content.. the URL also adds some characters like #,id= etc. Is there any way to do that? Appreciate all the help!

Comment: If that code is generating `#` in URL, some javascript is being executed, in that case it is a bit hard to grab the URL. But if that URL is redirecting then you can find an option in `cURL`s documentation to follow redirections.

Comment: I fiddled a lot with the cURL but since the HREF is HTTPS I couldn't get it changed value. Its also fine if I get the Header.

Answer (score 1):

You have to send the url of the iframe in javascript back to the server

```
var url = document.getElementById("iframe_id").contentWindow.location.href;
```

Then you can use jquery for example to send it back to the server

```
$.get('mywebpage.php?url='+url);
```

And finally use this url in a file_get_contents($_GET['url']) server side.

Comment: Hi, I have added a sample code, Can you please fix the code for me if its not much of a pain? :)

Comment: using `file_get_contents` for URLs is not a good idea. It is generally blocked on servers. Also why to use javascript when he himself is going to generate `src` URL.